# Docusign - set owner or sender using DocuSign API

Tags: api, docusignapi, sender, owner

We're using a API user (User A) to create envelopes using the DocuSign API. But the sender or owner shouldn't be the API user, but a user (User B) that can be selected in our custom front end.

Is there a way to do this? And will the sent enevelope appear in the Sent (or Draft) box in DocuSign for that selected user?

Answer (score 1):

In order to send envelopes as User B, you'll need to have your integration authenticate as User B. Most likely, this means setting up [Service Auth / JWT impersonation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-best-practice/) unless the person who should be listed as the sender is present to authenticate themselves for Auth Code Grant.